# find the area of a parallelogram with the sides are given using the fourth standard equation of straight line

Tags: analytic-geometry

the sides of a parallelogram are on the lines 
$$x-3y+20=0,\\ x+y+6=0,\\ x-3y-10=0 \text{ and} \\ x+y+2=0.$$
Find its area. solve using the fourth standard equation of the straight line.

Comment: What is the fourth standard equation of the straight line?

Comment: xcos(theta) + ysin(theta) = p

Comment: What are the first, second, and third standard equation of the straight line?

Comment: Maybe there is a smarter way. But this works. Find the intersections of your lines, then use http://www.jtaylor1142001.net/calcjat/Solutions/VCrossProduct/VCPAParallelogram.htm

Comment: julien, im not quite sure what are the first, second, and third standard equation of the straight line. thanks for the link you sent, but our teacher told us to solve using the fourth standard equation.

Answer (score 1):

A less mysterious answer than rlgordonma's would be to solve for the four intersections (four sets of 2x2 linear systems of equations; 3 will do in fact), and use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) for the area of one of the resulting triangles, twice that is your answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but there is a solution still less mysterious! Find the vertices, and then use scalar product to compute the area - it will lead to *much* less computation.

Answer (score 0):

First you should solve the eqns of the adjacent side and
Not the eqns which are parallel.then you would get the value of coordinates  then find the area of the triangle
 Separated by the diagonal then 2* area of the triangle